# how remove all but the first n chars

Tags: regular-expressions, search, deletion

How can I remove all but the first n characters of a every line in the file buffer?

What I tried

```
Mark region
C-x r k #but this is cumbersome when the length of lines are very varied, and there are over 100 lines
```

Comment: Try [rectangle editing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangles.html).

Comment: rectangle editing  misses segments when some lines in the middle are lengthy

Comment: Well... rectangle editing does what you tell it to do -- if it 'misses' segments it's because you didn't make your rectangle the appropriate width.  (I do know what you mean though -- it might not be *obvious* what the necessary width is, and it can indeed be a cumbersome solution.)

Answer (score 4):

You can do a `replace-regexp` like this:

- replace `^\(.\{15\}\).*$`
- with `\1`

This will match lines with at least 15 characters, and replace with the 1st 15 (which are saved as a match group).

Did you mention that n=15?

Comment: E.g., `(defun foo (beg end &optional n)
  (interactive "r\np")
  (let ((rgx  (format "^\\(.\\{%d\\}\\).*$" n)))
    (replace-regexp rgx "\\1" nil beg end)))`

Comment: @Drew your comment could be an independent answer.